# Replacing first occurance of a match with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am doing a find and replace with sed, replacing the BASH variable `$a` (when at the start of a new line) with the BASH variable `$b`:

```
sed -i "s#^$a#$b#" ./file.txt
```

This replaces all matches for `^$a`. How can I replace only the first occurrence of `^a` within the entire file?

Comment: I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -i "0,/^\$a/s//\$b/" ./file.txt
```

You can read more about this at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-29

Comment: When I try this, I get "sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'".

Comment: Yes, I use "$" instead of "/" because some of the items to be replaced contain "/", but do not contain any "#".

Comment: I think you shouldn't escape `$` between double quotes in a `sed` script to use `bash` variables inside it.

Comment: If your items contain `/` you can escape it with `\/`.

Comment: @Village: You will need to escape the first `#`. Try this: `sed -i "0,\#^$a#s##$b#" ./file.txt`. I removed the escapes before the dollar signs so the variable values will be substituted. Note that the address form `0,addr2` is specific to GNU `sed` (which you are using).

Answer (score 6):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed "s/^$var1/$var2/ ; ta ; b ; :a ; N ; ba" infile
```

Explanation:

```
s/^$var1/$var2/             # Do substitution.
ta                          # If substitution succeed, go to label `:a`
b                           # Substitution failed. I still haven't found first line to 
                            # change, so read next line and try again.
:a                          # Label 'a'
N                           # At this position, the substitution has been made, so begin loop
                            # where I will read every line and print until end of file.
ba                          # Go to label 'a' and repeat the loop until end of file.
```

A test with same example provided by Jaypal:

Content of `infile`:

```
ab aa
ab ff
baba aa
ab fff
```

Run the command:

```
sed "s/^$var1/$var2/ ; ta ; b ; :a ; N ; ba" infile
```

And result:

```
bb aa
ab ff
baba aa
ab fff
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -i 'x;/^./{x;b};x;/^'"$a"'/{s//'"$b"'/;h}' file
```

Or:

```
 sed -i ':a;$!{N;ba};s/^'"$a/$b"'/m' file
```