# sed only the last match pattern

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to `sed` only the last match pattern of a text file.

input file:

```
boy
boy
girl
boy
```

output file:

```
boy
boy
girl
boys
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114807/sed-replace-last-line-matching-pattern

Answer (score 16):

One method would be to reverse the file, replace only the first match, and then reverse it back again.

```
tac <file> | sed '1 s/boy/boys/' | tac | sponge <newfile>
```

tac will "concatenate and print files in reverse". sponge will "soak up standard input and write to a file". It's in the "moreutils" package on debian.

Comment: What's the benefit of piping to `sponge` compared with `tac > newfile`?  The disadvantage, if the data is big, is that there's an extra pipe which the data has to be copied into and out of, which slows things down.

Comment: Just what my fingers went for as I thought about the problem, really. It's not a robust, all-purpose solution, I'll grant you.

Comment: When I used `tac > file` to write this back to the same file (so `<newfile> = <file>`, intended behaviour like `sed -i`) it ended up blank (even though it worked with stdout), so I wrote it out to another file first and then renamed that. Maybe there's a better solution, but it worked for me.

Comment: @johnny if you redirect an output to a file, the file is created immediately; so something like `command < <file> > <file>` will always result in an empty file. that's the reason why you either have to use `... > <newfile>` or `... | sponge <file>`. if you don't have `sponge` installed, you can workaround it with something like this: `file=<file> && cp -vi --preserve=all "${file}" "tmp_${file}" && command < "tmp_${file}" > "${file}" ; rm -vi "tmp_${file}"` (yes, `cp` is used deliberately instead of `mv` to preserve hardlinks.)

Answer (score 8):

All you need is `$`:

```
sed '$s/boy/boys/'
```

Comment: Suppose there was another `girl` after the last `boy`?  This works on the specific example data, but not more generally.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/.*boy/&s/' file
```

Slurp the file into memory and substitute the last occurrence of the desired string using greed.

An alternative, less memory intensive solution:

```
sed '/.*boy/,$!b;//{x;//p;x;h};//!H;$!d;x;s//&s/' file
```

This uses the hold space to hold previous lines that contain the required string and sheds them when a new occurence of the required string is encountered. At the end of the file the last occurrence is in the hold space and is modified.

Another solution:

```
sed -z 's/.*boy/&s/' file
```

Comment: This is the only solution that looks for the last pattern match instead of just doing the substitution on the last line.

Comment: please explain it. this is not the correct way in Stack. after the solution, we need to explain the way.

Comment: @HosseinVatani the best way to see how both solutions work is to add the `--debug` option and then follow the flow using the input provided. HTH