# sed with su misinterprets sed negation

Tags: bash, sed

This is simplified version of my actual problem. 
Here's my test.data file

```
test.data
=========
PROD SEARCH_URL = "google.com" db name "customers"
TEST SEARCH_URL = "google.com" db name "emp"
```

For all the lines containing "TEST", I want to change the search domain from "google.com" to "bing.com"

Below sed command works fine to achieve this:

```
sed -rin '/PROD/!s/bing.com/google.com/' test.data
```

But the way my test environment is set up, I need to run the sed command using "su" as:

```
su root "sed -rin '/PROD/!s/bing.com/google.com/' test.data"
```

And this results in error

```
-bash: !s/bing.com/google.com/': event not found
```

From other stackoverflow quesrions, I have tried:
   escaping ! and enclosing it in ''. Nothing seems to work

Have also tried "set +H" as below and it doesn't work:

```
su root "set +H && sed -rin '/PROD/!s/bing.com/google.com/' test.data"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This may be a result of your simplification but surely the requirement "for all the lines containing TEST" would be better met with `/TEST/s/...` rather than `/PROD/!s/...`? And I think your `bing` and `google` may be the wrong way around.

Comment: That is correct, I probably oversimplified. the lines are much more complex so I kind of need to use the ! operator to exclude the lines that I don't want. But if you run my example commands, its easy to reproduce the problem

Comment: No probs, just thought I'd clarify. FWIW, the "event" reminds me of the csh history feature where `!` would be used to recall a specific command. I *think* this functionality is also in `bash` but I'm not sure why it would be relevant given it's inside single quotes.

Comment: you should escape `!`, and use `-c` option when running command with `su`. such as `su root -c "sed -rin '/PROD/\!s/bing.com/google.com/' test.data"`

Comment: @Feng, I have already tried escaping the negation to \! and I am actually running the command with -c, that does not make any difference!

Comment: @Amol I tested the two commands, they work well. `su root -c "sed -r '/TEST/s/google.com/bing.com/' test.data"` and `su root -c "sed -r '/PROD/\!s/google.com/bing.com/' test.data"`

Comment: The backslash escaping should work. Also, depending on your bash version you may have a slightly different behavior, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273889

Answer (score 0):

It appears the intepretation of the `!` history character is actually being done by the *current* shell which means turning it off within the `su`-created shell is too late.

Further, the line:

```
set +H && su ...
```

won't help since it looks like the *entire* line is subjest to history modifications as soon as you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, *before* the `set +H` takes effect. Even `set +H ; su ...` doesn't seem to help with that.

However, the following *does* appear to work, turning off history before the line that would use it:

```
set +H
su ...
set -H
```

See the following transcript for detail:

```
pax$ cat test.data
PROD google.com
ABCD google.com
DEFG google.com

pax$ set +H
pax$ su root -c "sed -rin '/PROD/!s/google/bing/' test.data"
Password: <blah blah blah>

pax$ cat test.data
PROD google.com
ABCD bing.com
DEFG bing.com
```

---

There is *also* a way to do this with a tool that *doesn't* require the `!` character at all (if, for some reason, the above does not work for you).

As per the following transcript, `awk` will do the job nicely (you just have to emulate the `sed` in-place editing:

```
pax$ cat test.data
PROD google.com
ABCD google.com
DEFG google.com

pax$ su root -c "awk '/PROD/{gsub(/google/,\"bing\")}1' test.data >xx && mv xx test.data"
Password: <blah blah blah>

pax$ cat test.data
PROD google.com
ABCD bing.com
DEFG bing.com
```

You have to escape the `"` characters *within* the string due to the outer `"` quotes but that's about as simple as it can be made, while still honoring the original intent (as I understand it).

Comment: So all these commands are invoked remotely over a transient ssh connection. Which means `set +H` and `sed` need to be run as part of a single command invocation if at all :(