# How to echo ![](../images/a.png) in bash?

Tags: bash

I have tried so many variations to echo the following string:

`![](../images/a.png)`

my attempts

```sh
b="a.pdf"

$ echo -n  "![](../images/""${b%.*}.png")
-bash: ![]: event not found

$ echo -n  "\![](../images/""${b%.*}.png"\)
\![](../images/a.png)
```

How to get:

```
![](../images/a.png)
```

Comment: `echo -n  '!'"[](../images/${b%.*}.png)"` would work

Comment: [`set +H` would also do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125658/how-to-escape-history-expansion-exclamation-mark-inside-a-double-quoted-string)

Comment: This isn't a programming question. This only happens when typing commands interactively, it's not a problem in scripts.