# Adding lines to multipath.conf through echo

Tags: linux, echo

Is it possible to add the following lines to multipath.conf through echo or anyother alternative command?

*##ORA_FRA_IRD01P3 1x100GB
multipath {
              wwid               350002ac006450f58
              alias                ORA_FRA_IRD01P3
       }*

There is a closed brace '}' at the end of the file. The above mentioned lines have to be pasted just above the closed brace '}' in the multipath.conf file.

Thanks,

Comment: This can be achieved by **sed** command, not by **echo**.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
tac multipath.conf | sed 's/}/}\n##ORA_FRA_IRD01P3 1x100GB multipath { wwid 350002ac006450f58 alias ORA_FRA_IRD01P3 }/ ; ta ; b ; :a ; N ; ba' | tac > multipath.conf.tmp && mv -f multipath.conf.tmp multipath.conf
```

Example:

```
[root@joeyoung.io stackoverflow]# cat multipath.conf
{
        {
                line1
                line2
                line3
                line4
        }
}
[root@joeyoung.io stackoverflow]# tac multipath.conf | sed 's/}/}\n##ORA_FRA_IRD01P3 1x100GB multipath { wwid 350002ac006450f58 alias ORA_FRA_IRD01P3 }/ ; ta ; b ; :a ; N ; ba' | tac > multipath.conf.tmp && mv -f multipath.conf.tmp multipath.conf
[root@joeyoung.io stackoverflow]# cat multipath.conf
{
        {
                line1
                line2
                line3
                line4
        }
##ORA_FRA_IRD01P3 1x100GB multipath { wwid 350002ac006450f58 alias ORA_FRA_IRD01P3 }
}
```

**Explanation**

`tac` prints out the file in reverse order line by line starting from the last line of the file.

`sed 's/}/}\n##ORA_FRA_IRD01P3 1x100GB multipath { wwid 350002ac006450f58 alias ORA_FRA_IRD01P3 }/` takes the first instance of `}` (which happens to the last instance of `}` in the file because `tac` prints the last line first) and replaces it with another `}`, followed by a newline, followed by the line of text that you wanted to insert into the file.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149155/2744166) explains the `; ta ; b ; :a ; N ; ba'`.

The output of the sed call is piped back through `tac` to put it back in the original order.

The output of the last `tac` called is written out to a temporary file because we can't overwrite the original version of the file just yet.

Double ampersand (`&&`) means that if the first command was successful, continue on with the next command.

Finally we forcefully rename the temporary file to multipath.conf with the `mv -f` command, thus overwriting the original contents.